# React children props is coming empty

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components where 1 of them should display its children but I can't see where I'm doing it wrong - the children props is coming empty.

This is the child component called `FeedGrid`, which displays fine:

```
const FeedGrid: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  <BgBox>
    <GridLayout>
      {Array(8)
        .fill(null)
        .map((_, idx) => (
          <CardPlugin />
        ))}
    </GridLayout>
  </BgBox>
);
```

And this is the parent component called `BgBox`:

```
const BgBox: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = (props) => (
  <Box paddingLeft={10} paddingRight={10} background="neutral100">
    <Box
      paddingTop={6}
      paddingBottom={6}
      background="neutral150"
      borderColor="neutral300"
      hasRadius
    >
      {props.children}
    </Box>
  </Box>
);
```

The `FeedGrid` component is being displayed but nothing inside, where it should be the children props. If I replace `{props.children}` for a the `CardPlugin` directly that works.

Can anyone tell me where's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What do you see if you log `props.children`?

Comment: If I log props to see if anything comes up I get {}

Comment: Odd. Make a codesandbox and share it.

Comment: You should be able to debug this yourself. Your code looks fine so it's likely the problem is with code you're not showing us. Spend some time debugging your code. What happens if you replace `<GridLayout>` with some text?

Comment: @AndyRay I'm trying to debug it for a long time in different ways but no success - that's I came here. If I replace the <GridLayout> for a text nothing is displayed too. But if I add a simple text above the {props.children} I get this text displayed. It's very odd this issue.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I'll try to setup a codesandbox for this.